# How to fetch a specific span tag on a webpage using Chrome console?

Tags: html, class, google-chrome, fetch, information-retrieval

I'm on a website and I'd like to fetch a list of a specific span.

Ex. Names1

How do I get the list of all the Names1 (each name on a new line), using the Google Chrome Console ?

Thank you very much for your help

Everything I tried came back with an error message (some saying that the span was undefined etc.)
I've tried:

```
var spanElements = document.querySelectorAll('span._ap3a._aaco._aacw._aacx._aad7._aade');

    // Initialize an empty array to store the names
    var namesList = [];

    // Loop through each <span> element and add its content to the names list
    spanElements.forEach(function(span) {
        namesList.push(span.textContent);
    });

    // Log the names list
    console.log(namesList);
});

it came back "undefined"
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or your question may be closed. We don't know what "Names1" means. Also, your query selector is looking for something with many classes on the same element, so it's likely your query selector string is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you require only one class name to be present on a `<span>` element for it to qualify as a "name"-span the following should do what you want:

```js
const classes="_ap3a._aaco._aacw._aacx._aad7._aade".split("."),
  names=[...document.querySelectorAll('span')]
   .filter(el=>classes.some(cl=>el.classList.contains(cl)))     
   .map(el=>el.textContent);
console.log(names.join("\n"));
```

```html
This is <span class="red _ap3a">Henry</span> 
and this is <span class="green _aaco">Susan</span>. 
And then there are <span class="_aacx blue">Claire</span>,
<span class="_aad7 _aacw">Anne</span>
and <span class="_aade">Tom</span>.
And this is not a name: 
<span class="noname">not-a-name</span>
```